How to create an online meeting event with a specific organiser using the Microsoft Graph API?
Is it possible to set the organiser while creating an online meeting event using the Microsoft Graph API?
My request so far:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"
Content-type: application/json

{
    "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "HTML",
        "content": "Does noon work for you?"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2017-04-15T12:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2017-04-15T14:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "location":{
        "displayName":"Harry's Bar"
    },
    "attendees": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address":"samanthab@contoso.com",
                "name": "Samantha Booth"
            },
            "type": "required"
        }
    ],
    "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
    "isOnlineMeeting": true,
    "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
}


I'm following this tutorial:


You can't set the organizer property it will always be inferred from where its being created, you can create a meeting on someone's behalf in a delegated mailbox https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-create-event-in-shared-delegated-calendar?tabs=http. If you use Application permissions (client_credentials flow) then in that case you just impersonate the organizer you want.
Another option is once you create a Meeting in the Event endpoint is that you can take the joinurl and modify it via the onlinemeeting endpoint and add another participant as a coorganizer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/meetingparticipantinfo?view=graph-rest-1.0
